# Script Jquery Slider with Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I've been trying to make a Jquery slider for the past few days but no luck. I was wondering if some one could help me give this Jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/b374B/1/ slider the final touch, I'm quite lost on the scripting side. Also know that this Jquery with carousel is based on the one from this site : http://halo.xbox.com/en-us

I'd appreciate all the instructions or tutorials on how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few good jQuery plugins that might do the trick:

- http://thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/
- http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/
- http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

If you have a general understanding of jQuery it should be easy to use any of these.

Comment: I've been trying to understand Jquery but I just get to the point where I set up everything and I don't know what to do next. But thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: It takes some time :\ 
using plugins and tutorials helped me when I first started.

Answer (score 0):

[**Nivo Slider**](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) most awesome jQuery Slider.

It is really simple to integrate with 16 unique transition effects.

[Advanced tutorial for using Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/)